# Vertical Plots in Vertical Triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-graphdrawing

So I want to have several vertical curves in a vertical triangle, like

[image: here] .

[image]

I tried several things, but simple three point arcs cross the boundary of the triangle. Plotting a sine (which is still not exactly what I want) seems to fail by positioning, the only real working option for turning the graph is in the following code:

```
    \documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O1) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (A1) at (-1,4);
    \coordinate (O2) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (1,4);
    \coordinate (O3) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (A3) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (O4) at (-1,4);
    \coordinate (A4) at (1,4);

    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
           (O1) edge[]  (A1);
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
           (O2) edge[]  (A2);
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
           (O3) edge[]  (A3);
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
           (O4) edge[]  (A4);
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
           (-1,0) edge[]  (1,2);
           (-1,4) edge[]  (1,6);
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
           (1,2) edge[]  (-1,4);
           (1,6) edge[]  (-1,8);

    \begin{scope}[rotate=-90]
    \draw[dashed] (0,0) plot[domain=0:3.14159265,smooth, variable = \y] (\y,            
    {sin(\y r)});
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Which produces the second picture. (I'm sorry for the formatting of this post, I don't really know how to work with pictures this long here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With pure TikZ code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.14pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   box/.style = {draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=4cm,
                 inner sep=0pt, node contents={}}
                        ]  
%
\node (n) [box];
\draw (n.south east) -- (n.west) -- (n.north east);
\draw[dashed,thin]
    (n.south east) to [bend left=45,looseness=1.50] (n.north east)
    (n.south east) to [bend left=30,looseness=1.25] (n.north east)
    (n.south east) to [bend left=15] (n.north east);
\node [above] at (n.south) {$r=0$};
\node [below] at (n.north) {$r=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=4cm] (graph){};
 \draw (graph.north east) -- (graph.west) node[pos=0.3,left]{$r=0$}
 -- (graph.south east) node[pos=0.7,left]{$r=0$};
 \draw[dashed] foreach \X in {1,2,3} 
 {(graph.south east) to[out=90+\X*45/4,in=-90-\X*45/4,looseness=1.7] (graph.north east)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]